# Mongo db multiple search on text and exact match word comes first

Tags: regex, mongodb

```
{
username:"R G Cellulars"
}
{
store:"gita"
}
{
store:"gita kitchan"
}
{
merchant:"sangita"
}
```

Now i need to search with gita keyword

I want to fectch records like

Exact match first

```
{
store:"gita"
}
{
store:"gita kitchan"
}

{
merchant:"sangita"
}
{
username:"R G Cellulars"
}
```

**Priority:**

Exact match first

Next starts with

Next contains

I need to search on multiple fileds.

Comment: Where is `gita` in `{ username:"R G Cellulars" }`???

Comment: Sorry, actually here username match with "username" : "Any Digital". here it's match with "Digital" keyword

Comment: Try this regex for exact match: `(?<![\w\d])gita(?![\w\d])`. Example:https://regex101.com/r/SLaaXq/1